# What happens if a Domain Alias is blocked?

Tags: plesk

I'm just wondering, what happens if the website that a domain alias is pointing to is blocked by filters eg: school or work ones?

For example:
If I have google.com and it's blocked will it then cause my domain alias - google.co.uk to fail to load? or will it load as usual?

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: depends entirely on the blocking system used.

Comment: Ok, so if it's just a simple url block on the parent domain then would it still work?

Comment: if they're blocking based on domain name and type in that exact domain name, sure. 

if I was doing it I'd block "google"  and anything with that word in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just a simple url block, it should work.